# No reporting in Crashlystics after changing FIrebase project

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have two projects.

1. connected like this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android).
2. connected with `Frabric plugin` on Android Studio.

First of all, My colleague connected the first way. It worked fine. After that I needed to create a new project for test. And I connected `Crashlystics` with `Fabric plugin`(I didn't know how my colleague connected at that time.)

Now, I needed to connect `Crashlystics` to the original version(which is 1).

However, It shows the crash graphs, But I don't get any reporting like which line got which error. I checked my test project and it gets the reporting.

So, I disconnected my account connected to `Fabric` and `my app`. And then, I get 0 reporting in both project.

At the moment, My setting is just like the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android). And of course, I have `google-services.json` file correctly.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The two methods that you've followed would have crash reporting at different places.

1st one would report everything on Firebase Console.
2nd would report everything on Fabric dashboard.

To connect fabric to firebase you would just need to migrate your app over to firebase with just a few button clicks and no code change.

My assumption is that you might not have stripped out the Fabric API Key (In your AndroidManifest.xml file) from your code hence the reports are not coming in at firebase console.